# Important packages in laravel are removed when installing laravel/socialite

Tags: laravel-10, laravel-socialite

when I use composer require laravel/socialite the folders in vendor/laravel/... are completely deleted and replaced by socialite related folders. But the old folders were deleted, resulting in an error that my project could not be opened.

After installing socialite:

[image: after installing socialite]

Before installing socialite:

[image: before installing socialite]

Is there any way to fix this problem? I have looked at many manual pages but none of them talk about this problem. I want to fix this problem so can use google sign in for my project.